# CMap InitHashTable size

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, hashtable

In my program, the size of `CMap` times 1.2 IIRC 6230 which is superior to the size I used to `InitHashTable` (which is 6203).

I put another `InitHashTable` value which is a prime number: 9973

So is this correct? Or I should choose a closer prime number to 6203. Or maybe can I choose a bigger prime number?

Comment: Use `std::map` if possible. `CMap` is strange with its instructions on prime numbers.

Comment: I really want to follow your advice, but I am working with an old code and it is not my business to modify it :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is test result for `CMap` with VS2015. It suggests using prime numbers doesn't make a big difference, and it doesn't matter if initialization is 20% more or less than expected value.

There is no error with or without prime numbers or initialization. I would assume that the reference to "collision" in `CMap`'s documentation is related to performance.

For larger data sets, you can just use the expected data size. For example if expected size is 6,000, then just use `map.InitHashTable(6000)`. Default value is 17, lower values will slow down performance.

There is also test result for `std::map` which doesn't need initialization and is very fast.

```
void test()
{
    CString msg;

    //build test vector
    int size = 100000;
    std::vector<CString> vs;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        CString s;
        s.Format(L"str%d", i);
        vs.push_back(s);
    }

    {//using prime number, 20% larger than expected size
        int t = GetTickCount();
        int init_size = 120011;

        CMap<LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, int, int> map;
        map.InitHashTable(init_size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            map[vs[i]] = i;

        msg.AppendFormat(L"CMap Initialized: %d, time:%d\n", init_size, GetTickCount() - t);
    }

    {//using non-prime number and 20% less than expected size
        int t = GetTickCount();
        int init_size = 80000;

        CMap<LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, int, int> map;
        map.InitHashTable(init_size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            map[vs[i]] = i;

        msg.AppendFormat(L"CMap Initialized: %d, time:%d\n", init_size, GetTickCount() - t);
    }

    {//using non-prime number and default initialization (m_nHashTableSize=17)
        int t = GetTickCount();
        CMap<LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, int, int> map;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            map[vs[i]] = i;
        msg.AppendFormat(L"CMap Initialized: %d, time:%d\n", 17, GetTickCount() - t);
    }

    {//std::map test
        int t = GetTickCount();
        std::map<CString, int> mp;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            mp[vs[i]] = i;
        msg.AppendFormat(L"std::map time:%d\n", GetTickCount() - t);
    }

    //error test:
    int init_size = 1000; //only a fraction of expected size!
    CMap<LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, int, int> map;
    map.InitHashTable(init_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        map[vs[i]] = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (map[vs[i]] != i)
        {
            AfxMessageBox(L"errorTest - fail");
            return;
        }
    }
    msg.AppendFormat(L"no error");

    AfxMessageBox(msg);
}
```

Test result: (release mode with optimization on)

```
CMap Initialized: 120011, time:31
CMap Initialized: 80000, time:47
CMap Initialized: 17, time:5110
std::map time:78
no error
```

result is just a rough estimate

Comment: I did a benchmark too, hash map size even when it's too small comparing to the expected size, there is no data loss. However, performance are decreased significantly (e.g. 0.5 s for a std::map comparing to 22s for a CMap<CString, LPCSTR, int,int> having a very small hash size when accessing data - if the hash table has a correct size CMap beats std::map e.g. 0.4 s against 0.5 s)

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` uses **Red-Black tree** and `CMap` is implemented as **hash-table**. So these are two totally different containers. According to MSDN for best performance, the hash table size should be a prime number. To minimize collisions, the size should be roughly 20 percent larger than the largest anticipated data set.

Comment: On second thought, `CMap` seems to have some advantages if you know the initial size. `std::map` can't set the initial size so it's slower. I ran some tests, it show that it doesn't matter if there is prime number or not, and it doesn't matter if the init size is 20% larger. It's fast as long as init size is roughly where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Barmak, if I use a big hash table (100 % larger than the supposed size), will I have problems like collisions ? (excuse my dumb question)

Comment: Aminos, The documentation is vague. "collision" probably refers to performance issues. If it were an error then you want to eliminate collisions, not minimize it. I think `CMap` tries to allocate a new item, it might see a collision with existing items, so it has to allocate a new item, this wastes a few nanoseconds. Perhaps this is what the documentation is warning about. I added some tests in the other answer.